# In Android, when overriding touch events, why is a call to super.onTouchEvent(event) required?

Tags: android, touch-event, gestures

In the tutorial at http://www.techotopia.com/index.php/Detecting_Common_Gestures_using_the_Android_Gesture_Detector_Class the author includes a call to the super.onTouchEvent(event) with a reminder to not forget it:

```
@Override 
public boolean onTouchEvent(MotionEvent event) { 
   this.gDetector.onTouchEvent(event);
   // Be sure to call the superclass implementation
   return super.onTouchEvent(event);
}
```

I am trying to figure out why this is necessary.  In the example in that tutorial, I removed the call to the superclass and simply returned this.gDetector.onTouchEvent(event) and saw no change in the results.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

From the Android source ([Activity.java](https://android.googlesource.com/platform/frameworks/base/+/android-l-preview_r2/core/java/android/app/Activity.java)):

```
public boolean onTouchEvent(MotionEvent event) {
  if (mWindow.shouldCloseOnTouch(this, event)) {
    finish();
    return true;
  }
  return false;
}
```

If you override this method and don't call `super.onTouchEvent(event)`, then that code would not be executed. Most of the times you don't want that to happen, even if it doesn't seem to have any obvious effect.

Comment: Thank you - that is the clarification I was looking for.  I knew there had to be a reason it was required, but I was having trouble determining it.

Answer (score 1):

Your are required to call the super method. Because if you leave it only for the `GestureDetector` - only the gesture detector will receive touch events. However, if you call the super method in the end. It will pass the touch event to other UI elements in the hierarchy.

Answer (score 0):

**super** is used to reference the parent class. So it is here used to call the method `onTouchEvent()` of parent class.

Comment: I understand that - my question is why is it *required*.  It seems to work appropriately without the call to the super.

Answer (score 0):

I was having problems using a touch listener of a webview without calling super.onTouchEvent, as the webview would not gain focus on touch. I assume the problem is the same when using a textarea. Calling a super function ensures that the proper steps are taken by the system, for instance focusing your view and opening the smart keyboard